# Open links in a new window

Tags: javascript

I have a div called 'divLinks'

I want all links inside the divLinks to open in a new window.

How can I write a cross-browser effective script to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming "a div called 'divLinks'" means that the div has an id of 'divLinks'...

```
var links=document.getElementById('divLinks').getElementsByTagName('a'), 
    len=links.length, i;
for (i=len; i--;) { links[i].target='my_external_window'; }
```