# javascript redirect to new window

Tags: javascript, redirect

I have this code that redirects to a page based on the value of a dropdown list:

```
<Script language="JavaScript">
function goto(form) { var index=form.select.selectedIndex
if (form.select.options[index].value != "0") {
location=form.select.options[index].value;}}
//-->
</SCRIPT>
```

How do I make that open in a new window?

Comment: Exact duplicate of [several](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3224374/17300) [other](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2636643/17300) [questions](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10242908/17300). Did you search before you asked?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I make a redirect page in jQuery/JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/503093/how-can-i-make-a-redirect-page-in-jquery-javascript)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
function goto(form) {
    var index = form.select.selectedIndex
    if (form.select.options[index].value != "0") {
        location = form.select.options[index].value;
        window.open(location);
    }
}​
```

For the full list of options available to `window.open`, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.open

Answer (score 4):

Make javascript function :-

```
 onBtnPress:function(){
        window.open("http://www.yashvekaria.com", "_blank");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
window.open(URL,name,specs,replace)
```

url: URL for new window

name: (optional) default is _blank

specs: (optional) Google JavaScript window.open for a complete list

replace: (optional) [true|false] replace history or append

Answer (score 0):

```
window.open(url, "nameOfTheWindow");
```

Check http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp to see the detailed options, most browsers support this, but some of them dones't work well with sizing the popup window.

Answer (score 0):

```
window.open(URL,name,specs,replace)
```

Check [here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp) for detailed usage of this.