# Redirect to external links with params in new tab Yii2

Tags: yii2

I'm trying to give a preview to users, when user makes any changes.
Currently I have an action called `actionPreview()`.
`actionPreview()` should open a website in new window, with some params.
 I have tried all the following,

```
public function actionPreview()
     {
       $this->redirect('http://www.yiiframework.com'); // opens a website in the same window


       $this->redirect('http://www.yiiframework.com',array('target'=>'_blank')); // gives an error 
     }
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thank You

Answer (score 2):

It's not possible to redirect to new window in PHP.

See these similar questions:

- [Header Location in new tab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12539011/header-location-in-new-tab)
- [redirect in a new window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/950518/redirect-in-a-new-window)

Use HTML for displaying preview link:

```
<a href='...' target='_blank'>...</a>
```

Or try JavaScript solution:

- [javascript redirect to new window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11694753/javascript-redirect-to-new-window)